# C# Regex.Replace match by the same amount of characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, text, replace

I like to know how to replace a regex-match of unknown amount of equal-signs, thats not less than 2... to the same amount of underscores

So far I got this:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "(={2,})", "");
```

What should I use as the 3rd parameter ?

EDIT: Prefferably a regex solution thats compatible in all languages

Comment: Any examples of input/output? If you just want to replace any `=` sign, just replace every single `=` with a single `_`. If you have `===`, it will become `___`.

Comment: But they have to be at least 2 sequential equal-signs, 1 equal sign should just remain a equal-sign

Comment: Then, that's an important part of the question that should have been mentioned! That's why sample input/output help determine the rules of the replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much less clear answer (in term of code clarity):

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "=(?==)|(?<==)=", "_");
```

If there are more than 2 `=` in a row, then at every `=`, we will find a `=` ahead or behind.

This only works if the language supports look-behind, which includes C#, Java, Python, PCRE... and excludes JavaScript.

However, since you can pass a function to `String.replace` function in JavaScript, you can write code similar to Alexei Levenkov's answer. Actually, Alexei Levenkov's answer works in many languages (well, except Java).

Comment: @user3160134: Not sure why you are accepting my answer. It is more confusing than the solution where you pass in a replacement function. I wrote this answer to show, rather than to advocate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Regex.Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead and analyze math:

```
string result = new Regex("(={2,})")
    .Replace(text, match => new string('_', match.ToString().Length));
```